# How to find out internet-facing resource (EC2, RDS etc) in AWS VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

Question is really simple, Where we can check in the VPC to find internet-facing resources?

There are 1 VPC and it has couple private subnets where EC2 instances are in (with security groups attached), couple public subnets where NAT gateways are in (with EIP addresses attached) and each subnets has its own route table.

Note that there are 1 Internet gateway and 1 Virtual private gateway attached to VPC.

Comment: ec2 -> network interfaces shows all the allocated addresses it your vpc, including RDS.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check for the resources in the public subnet. Another way is to capture the VPC network metadata using the [VPC Flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) and analyze the same using [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html). [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/learn-from-your-vpc-flow-logs-with-additional-meta-data/) is a blog on AWS around the same. Another way is to use the [VPC Ingress Routing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-ingress-routing-simplifying-integration-of-third-party-appliances/).